# SPARQL query to sort by property

Tags: sparql

Assume having the following triples in the triplestore, i.e. five resources that have both a "hierarchical structure" as well as a "horizontal order":

```
<kiwi> rico:isOrWasIncludedIn <fruits> .
<apple> rico:isOrWasIncludedIn <fruits> .
<plum> rico:isOrWasIncludedIn <fruits> .
<orange> rico:isOrWasIncludedIn <fruits> .
<banana> rico:isOrWasIncludedIn <fruits> .
<orange> rico:followsOrFollowed <plum> .
<banana> rico:followsOrFollowed <kiwi> .
<apple> rico:followsOrFollowed <orange> .
<plum> rico:followsOrFollowed <banana> .
```

How would I query the triplestore with SPARQL to return the resources that are included in `<fruits>` in correct order like:

```
<kiwi>
<banana>
<plum>
<orange>
<apple>
```

Comment: just write a SPARQL query with  a single triple pattern where the predicate and object are bound like in the first 5 triples and sort the subjects. Done. So what did you try?

Comment: Well, that would work if we assume that sorting the IRIs alphabetially would result in the correct order. However, that must not necessarily be true. Let me adapt the example a bit...

Comment: Can you walk us through with the setup of this problem? Like what sparql engine are you using? What environment are you working with, is this just a mock data, or the actual data you are working with? Finally, what is the purpose of this problem solving - pure academia or something else?

Answer (score 1):

To isolate those iris you can write a query like this:

```
PREFIX rico: <long form goes here>

SELECT DISTINCT ?iri WHERE 

{

?iri rico:isOrWasIncludedIn <fruits> .

}
```

I think I understand your request for order by. You could use a sub-query and bind a sequence of numbers to the entities in order - 1,2,3 etc. Then order by this new variable.

Comment: Thanks, Henri! My goal is to get them in the correct order as defined by the various "rico:isOrWasFollowing" properties. Binding numbers would mean I have to bind numbers explicitly to a resource – if I insert a new item somewhere in between, I would have to adjust all numbers then...

Comment: I see what you mean. Perhaps a sub-query where you specify that the `subject` == `predicate`? Would need to do something more with this then. You might need to adapt your ontology to make this possible.